# Suppose $A$ is rank 1. If $A^2 = cA$ for some constant $c$, is it true that for a non-zero vector $x$, $Ax = cx$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $A$ is rank 1 $A:X \to X$, finite dimensional $X$. If $A^2 = cA$ for some constant $c$, is it true that for a non-zero vector $x$, $Ax = cx$ generally for any such $A$ that meets this requirement?

I've been told this is true, but is it not necessary that $A$ is invertible? If I do
\begin{align*}
A^2 &= cAx \\
A^2x &= A(cx) \\
Ax &= cx
\end{align*}
then it seems to me that we require a left multiplication by $A^{-1}$ for the last equality to hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider rank 1 matrix $A=diag(1,0)$. $A^2=1\cdot A$ but $A(1,1)=(1,0)\neq (1,1)$.